# Save Access file in .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-access

How can I save an Access report in .net to the user's pc? I've tried using Access.SaveAsAXL, Docmd.OutputTo, and few other ways, but to no avail. The following is my latest attempt.

```
 string dbname = "D:\\filename.mdb";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application oAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(dbname, true);
        oAccess.Visible = true;
        var acFormatXLS = "Microsoft Excel (*.xls)";
        string id = "tblJobs.JobID=" + (Convert.ToInt32(GetMaxJobID())).ToString();

        try
        {
          oAccess.Run("BuildXAxisTimeLine", Convert.ToInt32(GetMaxJobID()));

          oAccess.SaveAsAXL(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcObjectType.acReport, "rptChartData", "D:\\report.xls");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            //oAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase();
        }
```

The error i receive is:

> hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The followig code solved my problem. place this in the try section as shown above instead of oAccess.SaveAsAxl line of code and right under the .Run line of code.

```
oAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport("rptChartData", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcView.acViewPreview, null,id);
              oAccess.DoCmd.OutputTo(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, "rptChartData", acFormatXLS, "D:\\reportname.pdf",false, null, null);
```